# Forcing parent div(table) to extend to max-width

Tags: html, css, layout

The following snippet represents the relevant parts of the web page.

```
<div id="a" style="min-width: 300px; max-width: 800px; display: table">
    <!-- Placeholder -->
    <iframe style="width: 100%">
    </iframe>
<div>
```

The parent div has adaptive layout. We don't know about the concrete value of `max-width` and we are only able to modify the `placeholder` or the `iframe`. **We cannot modify the wrapper**.

With this setup the `iframe` will be 300px wide. If we filled the placeholder with enough text, then the `iframe` would be 800px wide.

The goal is to make the `iframe` as wide as the parent `div`'s max-width without ugly workarounds.

Answer (score 1):

Use position `absolute` for `iframe` and `relative` for the parent:

```
<div id="a" ">
    <!-- Placeholder -->
    <iframe></iframe>
<div>

#a {
    position:relative;   
    max-width:800px; 
    min-width:300px;
}
#a iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[**Updated JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/o5qdjyy6/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Your wrapping div doesn't have an actual width, so if you would set it to `100%` it would adapt to the screen width and won't overlap or exceed the `min-width` and `max-width`.

```
#a {
    min-width: 300px; 
    max-width: 800px; 
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/b1voz8tg/)

Answer (score 0):

Since your wrapper `div` is a `display: table` element, you should make both the `iframe` and the Placeholder to be `display: table-row`.

This would fit them to the parent's width.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. Maybe the goal was not clear, updated a it little bit.

Answer (score 0):

The parent width could be 100%(using min/max-width too), and the iframe will just inherit. I'm using borders to show how the iframe fits the parent.

```
<div id="a" style="min-width: 300px; width: 100%; max-width: 800px; border: 1px solid red;">
    <!-- Placeholder -->
    <iframe style="width: inherit; border: 1px solid blue;">
    </iframe>
<div>
```